# How Google crawler see jquery link redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, seo, googlebot

I have a link

```
<a href="/my-webpage">Link</a>
```

and that webpage exists, and link works.

Now, when that link is placed in the content of some other webpage that has url eg.

```
http://example.com/questions
```

I want to redirect my link to

```
/questions/my-webpage
```

and open the same page as before.

If webpage has url http://example.com/answers , my link will redirect to /answers/my-webpage  and it will open the same content as before

I want to keep url structure.. I can do this with jquery, but Im worried about seo. I wanna know will google  restrict me because of link redirection?

As I understood, crawler collect href values, and add them to adds them to its list of pages to crawl. My first link ( /my-webpage ) will be regular, my second link (/questions/my-webpage) will open the same content.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't performing cloacking or any other black hat techniques, then you should be ok. Google is capable of executing Javascript, so it is likely to understand and accept what you are doing.